# Armijo-Goldstein - Backtracking

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a backtracking line search using the Armijo-Goldstein condition to adapt my stepsize $t$ adaptively.

I start with two paramteters $\alpha \in (0, 1/2)$ and $\beta \in (0.1)$, and my starting condition $t = 1$. My input is $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$

I repeat $t:=\beta*t$ until the Armijo - Goldstein condition is met:

$$f(x+t\Delta x) < f(x) + \alpha t\nabla f(x)^T\Delta x $$

I understand parts of it, but am also confused on how to implement this in code-form.

I dont really understand what $\Delta x$ means in this context and I dont understand either why I would need to use the transpose of my gradient $\nabla f(x)$ (does the transpose switch the gradient vector from ascent to descent?). I know it has to do with directional derivatives, but maybe im just confused with the notation.

Here a bit of pseudocode:

```
while f(x + t*delta_x)<(f(x)+alpha+ np.transpose(gradient(x))*delta_x):
    t*=beta
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: $\Delta x$ is your step. You need to transpose the gradient to have a dot product.

Comment: Thank you, so then $\Delta x = x_{old} - x_{new}$ ?

Comment: $\Delta x$ is a vector specifying the descent (or ascent) direction. In the case of gradient descent $\Delta x = -\nabla x$. In the Newton-Raphson method $\Delta x = -(\nabla^2 f)^{-1}\nabla f$ where $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian of $f$. Your choice of descent direction will depend on your optimization algorithm